# Gmail "+" sign trick, now they ask me to send requests from the "+" sign address

Tags: gmail

I use xxxx+ebay@gmail.com registered an account on Ebay. I have an order issue and contacted them with xxxx@gmail.com and they ask me to reply with  xxxx+ebay@gmail.com, or they can't verify I am the owner of that account. how to do this? I can't log in with xxxx+ebay@gmail.com

Comment: Please refer to this answer. I did not google the right words.
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3598/is-there-any-way-to-send-an-email-from-a-gmail-plus-address

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related probably better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/